# skipping an undo action in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a long sequence of commands that I would like to undo from a document.  In the very beginning, there is a complex action that I do not want to undo.  Is there any way for me to skip an action in the undo list?

Comment: No, but most actions can be undone without the 'undo' command. As a bad example, you could bold a word, then either undo or press bold again to unbold. If you gave us more information about the problem you're trying to solve, maybe we can help you with a workaround.

Comment: Sure.  It's actually quite ridiculous.  I have a 500 page document that I am splitting up using the master document feature in word.  I'm using the document to automatically split the big document into about 500 separate subdocuments.  The filename is based on the first words which are typically formatted: '127. Command Name.'  Word will name this file '127'  If I delete the period, word names the file: '127 Command Name'  Great!  

1. Do that 500 times.
2. Create subdocuments.
3. Try to put all 500 periods back in by using undo, but 'create subdocument' command is in the way.